# Show equivalences concerning independence

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. We say, that $(E_i\in\mathcal{A}:i\in I)$ is a family of independent events, if for any finite subset $I_0\subset I$ it is $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I_0}E:i)=\prod_{i\in I_0}\mathbb{P}(E_i)$. Show that the following statements are equivalent: **(1)** $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ are independent events **(2)** $(\sigma(E_i))_{i\in I}$ indepedent **(3)** $(1_{E_i})_{i\in I}$ independent.

Before I show you my proof, I'll give you the theorems resp. definitions we had in our reading in order to be able to use them here.

*Definition 1*

A family $(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\mathcal{E}_i\subset\mathcal{A} (i\in I)$ is called independent, if for any finite subset $I_0\subset I$ and any choice $E_i\in\mathcal{E}_i, i\in I_0$, it is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I_0}E_i)=\prod_{i\in I_0}\mathbb{P}(E_i).
$$

*Theorem 1*

Is $(\mathcal{E_i})_{i\in I}$ independent in the sense above and all $\mathcal{E}_i\cup\left\{\emptyset\right\}$ are closed under $\cap$, then $(\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i))_{i\in I}$ is independent.

*Definition 2*

The family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of random variables is called independent if $(\sigma(X_i))_{i\in I}$ is independent.

I think *Definition 1*, *Definition 2* and *Theorem 1* are exactly what I need for my proof. Here it is:

**Proof**

$(1)\implies (2)$:

Let $(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\mathcal{E}_i\subset \mathcal{A} (i\in I), \mathcal{E}_i=E_i, E_i\in\mathcal{A}, i\in I$ be an independent family.

Then $\mathcal{E}_i\cup\left\{\emptyset\right\}=\left\{E_i,\emptyset\right\}, i\in I,$ is closed under sections, because $E_i\cap E_i=E_i\in\mathcal{E}_i$ and $E_i\cap\emptyset=\emptyset\in\mathcal{E}_i$. Corresponding *Theorem 1* then $(\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i))_{i\in I}=(\sigma(E_i))_{i\in I}$ is independent.

$(2)\implies (3)$:

Suppose that $(\sigma(E_i))_{i\in I}$ is independent. For all $i\in I$ it is $\sigma(1_{E_i})=\sigma(E_i)=\left\{\Omega,\emptyset,E_i,E_i^C\right\}$ so $(1_{E_i})_{i\in I}=(\sigma(E_i))_{i\in I}$. So corresponding *Definition 2* the family $(1_{E_i})_{i\in I}$ is independent.

$(3)\implies (1)$:

Suppose that $(1_{E_i})_{i\in I}$ is independent, i.e. $(\sigma(1_{E_i}))_{i\in I}=(\left\{\Omega,\emptyset,E_i,E_i^C\right\})_{i\in I}$ is independent. By *Definition 1* that means that for any finite subset $I_0\subset I$ and for any choice $X_i\in\left\{\Omega,\emptyset,E_i,E_i^C\right\}$ it is $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I_0}X_i)=\prod_{i\in I_0}\mathbb{P}(X_i)$.

So consider any finite subset $I_0\subset I$ and choose $X_i=E_i, i\in I_0$. Then it is $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I_0}E_i)=\prod_{i\in I_0}\mathbb{P}(E_i)$. Corresponding to the definition that is given in the task itself, that means that $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ is independent.

$\diamondsuit$

Please give me a feedback if my proof is right or not. Would be very kind!
Would like to know if I am right and if my efforts are appropriate.

Sincerely yours,

math12